# ¿Como puedo crear enlaces o acceso directo a un archivo en android?

Tags: android

Quiero ser capas de crear enlaces o acceso directos de ficheros de mi carpeta /data con los directorios de la /sdcard. En android no se como crear he tenido varios intentos utilice lo siguiente:
A)
`try {
Process symlink = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ln -s /data/data/com.Misdatos /sdcard/Misdatos");
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}`

Pero no crea nada ni un fichero de acceso directo como en linux nada (No se si en android se tienen que ver los enlaces simbólicos)

Otro:

```
try {
    Os.symlink("/data/data/com.Misdatos", "/sdcard/Misdatos");
} catch (ErrnoException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Pero el problema de este es que es para android 5.0 y necesito para android 4.0 o mínimo android 4.1 en adelante.

Y mi ultimo intento era utilizar la clase Files pero esta no se incluye en la sdk de android.

Si conocen alguna manera o observan que he cometido un error en mis códigos o material por favor comunicármelo. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede ejecutar como `Process` en la línea de comandos:

```
Process symlink = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ln -s /ruta/archivo /ruta/accesodirecto");
```

Tené en cuenta que Android permite *symbolic links*, pero algunos sistemas de archivos no, y no podrás crear enlaces ahí. Por ejemplo, no se pueden crear en FAT.

Viendo que intentas crear en enlace en la sdcard, y lo más probable es que sea una partición FAT, la respuesta sería que **no se puede**.

Comment: Ok no se puede crear en la sdcard, pero en la memoria interna en el mismo directorio data se creara. Gracias

Comment: Gracias ya entiendo lo que hace Link2SD

Answer (score 1):

**Programaticamente esto no es posible**, la única forma de realizarlo es acceder al archivo mediante un explorador de archivos y crear un shortcut (enlace) con la opción: "Agregar al Escritorio" ("Add to Desktop").

Agrego dos artículos en los cuales se explica el procedimiento:

http://www.tuexpertomovil.com/2015/01/28/como-crear-un-acceso-directo-a-un-fichero-en-la-pantalla-de-inicio-de-un-android/

http://www.tomsguide.com/us/create-file-shortcut-in-android,news-21283.html